# Swift Save UITextView Text to .Pdf, .Doc and .Txt file formate and Display

Tags: ios, swift

My Scenario, I am trying to save UITextView Text with Three format .pdf, .doc and .txt. Here, formate option user can choose based on alert option. Once Its saved need to show in Preview controller for file sharing. How to achieve this?

```
func createPDF(text:String, filename:String) {

        // 1. Create Print Formatter with input text.
        let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: text)

        // 2. Add formatter with pageRender
        let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
        render.addPrintFormatter(formatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)

        // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect
        let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
        let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
        render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

        // 4. Create PDF context and draw
        let rect = CGRect.zero

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, rect, nil)

        for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
            render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        // 5. Save PDF file
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/\(filename).pdf", atomically: true)
        print("saved success:\(documentsPath)\(filename)")
        listFiles()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code :)

```
let txtData = Data(textView.txt.utf8)
do {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let filePath = (documentsPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(filename).pdf")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        // pdfData created by your code above
        // txtData for ".txt"
        pdfData.write(to: url)

        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)

        // Use your desired viewController here, or just use the rootViewController
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch (let error) {
        print("\(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadBassio. Btw what about .txt and .doc files. Is it possible to store by using same function?

Comment: Ok. Thank You @MuhammadBassio

Comment: my question is how to create textview.text to .pdf, .docx and .txt. Want to convert and save into local and share option. Based on your above code looks overwriting process. Could you please clarify more about it?

Comment: check the updated answer :) , not sure about `.doc`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct you need show documents
You can do this with `QLPreviewController`
More info in -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/cl/QLPreviewController
https://medium.com/@garg.vivek/quick-display-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller-eaca97928c7a

`QLPreviewController` have sharing control