# Swift UIDocumentInteractionController not launching for preview my file

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am storing local some files and getting path to assigning UIDocumentInteractionController file path but `UIDocumentInteractionController` not opening.

My Code Below

```
func filepreview(filepath: String) {
        let dc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath))
        dc.delegate = self
        dc.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }
```

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

Comment: where you call `filepreview`

Comment: @Sh_Khan after save pdf file into local, I am calling this function

Comment: @Sh_Khan please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849245/swift-save-uitextview-text-to-pdf-doc-and-txt-file-formate-and-display